# Checking for Multicollinearity in Python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-analysis, statsmodels

I would like to check for multicollinearity in Python on a set of data involving both binary and continuous variables in preparation for logistic regression. I am using `statsmodels` with `pandas` for this task, but found that the summary/fit doesn't do a check for multicollinearity as R does. Is there some way of adding this functionality or some other way of completing this task? Any help would be very much appreciated!